# clojurescript waiting for callback

Tags: asynchronous, callback, clojurescript

I have a function which returns its result by a callback function. Almost like multiple http-request libraries does.

A lot of times i need to call this function multiple times to get different data.

```
(get-data "key-a" (fn [res-a]
  (get-data "key-b" (fn [res-b]
    (get-data "key-c" (fn [res-c]
      (do-something res-a res-b res-c)))))))
```

I'm trying to build a function which make the above work like this:

```
(get-multi-data ["key-a" "key-b" "key-c"] 
                do-something)
```

I should get the data requested in the vector and pass the results to the callback. Question 1: How could a function like this look?

Question 2: Is it possible by using core.async to make a funktion which simple returns the data? And hide the callbacks altogether?

```
(let [res (get-multi-data ["key-a" "key-b" "key-c"])]
  (do-something res))
```

Comment: I'd try to use `manifold` for this. There is a [CLJS port](https://github.com/dm3/manifold-cljs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function that returns a `get-muti-data` function for a given `get-data` function:

```
(defn multi-caller [data-getter] 
   (fn [xs callback]  
      (let [f (fn f [xs res] 
                (if (seq xs) 
                    (data-getter (first xs) #(f (rest xs) (conj res %)))
                    (apply callback res)))] 
           (f xs []))))
```

This would allow you to write

```
((multi-caller get-data) 
   ["key-a" "key-b" "key-c"] 
   do-something)
```

to achieve what you ask for.

Note that the get-data calls will be performed sequentially, so you do not benefit from parallelism.

---

As regards core.async, you have to do all the fun stuff inside go-blocks.
It is not possible to define a normal clojurescript function that does all the async stuff and *then* eventually returns a result to the caller.